# cannot loop oo components in a usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a bit confused.  I  implemented my own UserControl and  I want  that my control  discover Components (like binding source) hosted in the same Control at design time.

Code is like this:

```
private void FindComponentByName(string aName)  
{  
   foreach(Component component in this.Container.components)  
   {  
      if (Component.ToString()==aName)  
       {  
        dosomething();  
        break;   
        }  
   }  
}
```

This code is not working either at design time  or run time  as  Container  is  always  null.

If  I  run  this  code in  a  Form   not  in  a  UserControl

```
private Component FindComponentByName(string aname)  
        {  
            Component result = null;  
            foreach (Component component in this.components.Components)  
            {  
                if (component.ToString() == aname)  
                {  
                    result = component;  
                    break;  
                }  
            }  
            return result;  
        }
```

it  works,   as   components  is not  null  and  I  manage to retrieve  all  components.

I  need  to  do  that  at  run  time   and   at  design-time  too.

Can  someone please  explain  me   what's my mistake?
Thanks and regards
paolo

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like this:

```
private void FindComponentByName(string aName)  
{  
    Control c = FindComponentByName(this);
    if (c != null)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
}

private Control FindComponentByName(Control c, string aName)  
{
   if (c.Name == aName)
   {
       return c;
   }

   foreach(var control in c.Controls)  
   {  
      //recurse into containers controls to make sure we visit all depths
      Control found = ctrl.FindComponentByName(control, aName);
      if (found != null)
           return found;
   }
   return null;
}
```

You could even make that as an extension method so you can call that on whatever control  you need it:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Control FindControlWithName(this Control control, string aName)
    {
         if (control.Name == aName)
         {
            return control;
         }
         foreach(var ctrl in control.Controls)
         {
             Control found = ctrl.FindControlWithName(aName);
             if (found != null)
                 return found;
         }
         return null;
    }
}
```

and you can call it like:

```
if (someControl.FindControlWithName("hola") != null)
{
    dosomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but  the  Controls property  only  returns  cvisual  controls  not  non-visual controls (Components)  like  e.g.  BindingSource.

Comment: My issue was solved here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/23f714a5-dc38-4632-bb99-116c9d9cfe2f

Thanks all  for  your help

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found this solution which can be used by several parent class types (I present it as the extension defined for UserControl, but can be used for Form or Class).

```
public static class UserControlExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllMembersByType<T>(this UserControl sourceObj, Type requiredType)
    {
        var members = sourceObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        var found = members.Where(fi => fi.FieldType.Equals(requiredType));

        List<T> items = new List<T>();
        foreach (var fld in found)
        {
            T val = (T)fld.GetValue(sourceObj);
            items.Add(val);
        }

        return items;
    }

    public static T GetMemberByNameAndType<T>(this UserControl sourceObj, string requiredName, Type requiredType)
    {
        var members = sourceObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        var found = members.Where(fi => fi.FieldType.Equals(requiredType) && fi.Name == requiredName);

        if (found.Any())
        {
            var fld = found.FirstOrDefault();
            T val = (T)fld.GetValue(sourceObj);
            return val;
        }

        throw new Exception("No member found.");
    }


}
```